# Component doesn't re-render when props change using useState hook

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Everytime I get new data in data prop but the component dont re-render untill I call `handlePanelSelection()`

```react
function StepPanel({ data, getTranslations }) {
  const [panelsData, changePanel] = useState(data);

  function handlePanelSelection(panelId) {
    switch (panelId) {
      case 8:
        changePanel(getTranslations.NeeSubCategory);
        break;
      default:
        changePanel(data);
        break;
    }
  }
  return (
    <>
      {panelsData.map(details => {
        const imgsrc = requireContext('./' + details.image);
        return (
          <div key={details.id} className="block-list">
            <div className="left-block">
              <img src={imgsrc} alt="" />
            </div>
            <div className="right-block">
              <h3>{details.title}</h3>
              <p>{details.description}</p>
              <label htmlFor="radio1" className="radio-btn">
                <input
                  type="radio"
                  onClick={() => handlePanelSelection(details.id)}
                  name="radio1"
                />
                <span></span>
              </label>
            </div>
          </div>
        );
      })}
    </>
  );
}
```

but when I remove the hook like below it works

```react
function StepPanel({ data, getTranslations }) {
 
  return (
    <>
      {data.map(details => { ... })}
    </>
  )
}
```

I want to implement a functionality that when I get new data in data props the component gets re-render but also when I need to internally re-render i.e. like I change `panelId = 8`, then also it gets re-render, is it possible with this approach?

The above code seems to rerender but with the same data every time i.e. Its not updating the `panelData` everytime although everytime the data props is being provided with a new updated value

[image: console image]

Comment: please show the error in your console. it will have useful information.

Comment: Hello @LongNguyen I have consoled for the error, it seems to rerender but the data in panelsData does not change every-time its showing the same results although the data props is giving me the updated value every-time I will update my question for correct query

Answer (score 73, accepted):

This is because when you do this:

```
const [panelsData, changePanel] = useState(data);
```

You're only using your `data` prop as the **initial value** of `panelsData`. When the props change, the new data will be ignored because `panelsData` has its own state (well, it's a useState hook!).

That's why you have to explicitly call `changePanel` to change the state. *That's the whole idea!*

If you want to observe the `data` prop and update the state accordingly, you could use a `useEffect` hook with `data` as dependency (that means, it'll run only when `data` changes), like this:

```
useEffect(() => {
  changePanel(data);
}, [data]);
```

Comment: Thank you so much @ezakto that works exactly I want, and answer my problem.

Comment: perfect solution to what was ailing me as well. Good explanation too. I didn't know you could pass props to useEffect like that, I thought it was state only.

Comment: @YungGun You can set anything in the array of dependencies. When the component re-renders, it'll check all the elements of the array to see if at least one has changed, no matter where the value comes from.

Comment: Brilliant solution! I kept thinking, "If only there was a native way to set state _only_ when the prop changed." It's been a long day...

Comment: Thank you, I too didn't realize props could be used as useEffect deps

Comment: **That's the whole idea!** The moment I could hear it clicking in my brain..

Answer (score 0):

Have you ever try useEffect to handle re-render of component:

```
function handlePanelSelection(panelId) {
    switch (panelId) {
      case 8:
        changePanel(getTranslations.NeeSubCategory);
        break;
      default:
        changePanel(data);
        break;
    }
}
useEffect(() => {

}, [panelsData]) // just pass panelsData into here
// Component will re-render when panelsData change.
```

Comment: Hello @jdn I tried to use the above code and consoled for the error it seems to rerender but the data in panelsData does not change every-time its showing the same results although the data props is giving me the updated value every-time

Answer (score 0):

Does it work if you replace this part of your code?

```js
  // this block creates new function when re-render
  // replace
  function handlePanelSelection(panelId) {
    switch (panelId) {
      case 8:
        changePanel(getTranslations.NeeSubCategory);
        break;
      default:
        changePanel(data);
        break;
    }
  }
  // by
  const handlePanelSelection = useCallback(()=> {
    switch (panelId) {
      case 8:
        changePanel(getTranslations.NeeSubCategory);
        break;
      default:
        changePanel(data);
        break;
    }
  }, [data, getTranslations])
```

Answer (score -1):

Instead of using useEffect() as mentioned by @ezakto we can do like this:

```
const copyData = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data));

if(panelsData !== copyData){
    changePanel(data);
}
```

So that their will be no re-renders and your application will be somewhat efficient.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).